# Is a possible use of a Mill's constant the encapsulation/encryption of messages?

Tags: reference-request, cryptography, computational-mathematics, constants

> I wonder if the way that [Mill's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) is defined could provide a good data encapsulation and encryption method if instead of encapsulating primes, for instance a simple ASCII message is encapsulated into the intervals generated by Mill's method. Mill's constant is always associated to the initial original idea of encapsulating an infinite set of primes, but: what if the constant is used to encapsulate a finite set of values required for some calculation or safe communication?

This is an example: for small messages it is totally possible to encapsulate
each character of an ASCII message in a Mill's (-demonstration like) $[N^2,(N+1)^2]$ interval using each ASCII code of each character (in this case we can use a power of two interval because there is no restriction regarding the existence of the values we store in the interval).

For instance, the ASCII value of $A$ is $65$, $B$ is $66$, ..., $Z$ is $90$, etc. so it is possible to encapsulate each single character of the message inside $[N^2,(N+1)^2]$ intervals as $C_n=N^2+V$, where $V$ is the ASCII value of the character. The only restriction is that the interval must be big enough to handle an ASCII code: small intervals like $[1^2,2^2],[2^2,3^3]...[9^2,10^2]$ are not valid because the ASCII value plus the lower bound of the interval, $N^2$, is greater than the upper bound $(N+1)^2$, but for instance, any interval $[N^2,(N+1)^2]$ greater than $[20^2,21^2]$ would be fine to encapsulate an ASCII character in the way explained above.

The generation of the Mill's constant would be done as usual. For instance after encapsulating a message of $5$ characters, the Mill's constant $A_{5}$ is generated. That constant is able to generate the characters back, by using the character representing-function $C_n=\lfloor A^{2^n} \rfloor - (\lfloor A^{2^{n-1}} \rfloor)^2 $, $n \in [0..5]$.

Example: **message** = "Hello"

$N_{0}=20^2, C_{0}=20^2+Ascii(H)$

$N_{1}=C_{0}^2, C_{1}=N_{1}+Ascii(e)$

$N_{2}=C_{1}^2, C_{2}=N_{2}+Ascii(l)$

$N_{3}=C_{2}^2, C_{3}=N_{3}+Ascii(l)$

$N_{4}=C_{3}^2, C_{4}=N_{4}+Ascii(o)$

Then the Mill's constant is $A=A_{4}=C_{4}^{\frac{1}{2^4}}$. With this constant is possible to recalculate each $C_{n}=\lfloor A^{2^n} \rfloor$ and then recover the ASCII values $V_n=C_n-C_{n-1}^2$

Finally:

**message**$=V_0.V_1.V_2.V_3.V_4=H.e.l.l.o="Hello"$ where "." means concatenation of characters.

Probably the cost of the generation of the constant makes this theoretically possible but impossible to perform due to the accuracy required (decimals required to know about the constant to encrypt properly a very long message).

> I would like to ask the following questions:
>
> 1. Has this approach been tried before? Are there references to this kind of 
>      "encryption by constant" method?
> 2. Would it be useful for some kind of encoding scheme? e.g.: it might be possible to encrypt a path of a graph in a constant, using the value of the nodes as the value encapsulated on each iteration and then "decode" the value and use the path for some decision tree. Thank you!

Comment: In principal you can use Mill's constant to encrypt a message. But there are two problems : $1)$ The code is not safe, if someone knows that the constant was used. $2)$ Only a few primes can be deducted from the constant because the sequence grows very fast.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the feedback, in this case the encrypted data are not primes,but ASCII characters.As you mention the main problem would be the growth rate.I wonder if for small messages,telegram-like,it would be useful. The code could be safe if you play with three values: the power that is used ($2$,$3$...$k$) the starting point $n$, and the starting interval ($20^2$ in the example, but could be any interval). Any combination of those three elements would provide a quite safe encoding if the sender and the receiver know exactly the values (but brute force could be able to find it probably).

Comment: If you really need a good code , I would suggest to calculate the moebius function for the numbers in an intervall and convert it to binary digits. Then, you can use the well-known xor-based encription. You just have to know a secret start value (it can have $30$ or even $40$ digits because factoring such numbers is absolutely routine) and produce the bits beginning with this starting value. If you skip the numbers that are not squarefree, you probably get a pseudo-random-sequence which should exhibit good randomness.

Comment: I tried it and it worked very well. It is not proven that the pseudo-random-sequence exhibits good randomness, but it is likely to be so.

Comment: @Peter very nice approach, thank you for all the information! This time I was interested in Mill's constant because I am studying the original paper and trying to look for more applications of it (kind of lateral thinking)